Can't delete file properly, error 404 not found
why doesn't my form delete files as it should, laravel displays the error message 404 not found. I created a delete button and issued a form with capital.
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete{{ $data->id }}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>

view form delete
@foreach ($pengaduan as $data)
<div id="delete{{ $data->id }}" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header flex-column">
                <div class="icon-box">
                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i>
                </div>
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100">Pengaduan UP3 {{ $data->up3 }} ?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Yakin Ingin Menghapus Data Ini.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a href="/pengaduan/delete/{{ $data->id }}">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach

my Controller
public function delete($id)
    {
        $pengaduan = PengaduanModel::findOrFail($id);

        if ($pengaduan->foto_aduan) {
            Storage::delete('public/foto_aduan/' . $pengaduan->foto_aduan);
        }

        $pengaduan->delete();

        return redirect()->route('pengaduan')->with('pesan', 'Data Berhasil Dihapus !!!');
    }

and routes
Route::get('/pengaduan/delete/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\PengaduanController::class, 'delete']);

Previously, I always used this method to handle the delete function, but now I don't know why a 404 not found occurs.
I have tried
php artisan route:clear and
php artisan route:cache
but there is no effect

did you try php artisan route:list to check the route if it exist?

In HTML, create a proper DELETE route
<form action="{{ url('/pengaduan/delete/'.$data->id) }}" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>

the route
Route::delete('/pengaduan/delete/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\PengaduanController::class, 'delete']);

In controller
public function delete($id)
{
    $pengaduan = PengaduanModel::findOrFail($id);

    if ($pengaduan->foto_aduan) {
        Storage::delete('public/foto_aduan/' . $pengaduan->foto_aduan);
    }

    $pengaduan->delete();

    return redirect()->route('pengaduan')->with('pesan', 'Data Berhasil Dihapus !!!');
}


Addition
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache


it doesn't work, 404 not found

php artisan optimize and check your route:list , is there the route that you wanna use

@IrfanChaniago how come 404? check your routes

@AbdullaNilam when I check with php artisan route:list
the desired route is in the list,
This
GET|HEAD complaint/delete/{id}

It is the Route::delete route. Check the answer

@HerrysAghistaRachman it doesn't work

@AbdullaNilam Yes, I tried that answer earlier, but it didn't work. So I returned to my initial code, and checked the route list.
When I returned to the script according to that answer, it was also the same in the list
DELETE complaint/delete/{id} ...................... generated::ssknPnImA8nC0fF0 › PengaduanController@delete
but the same, it doesn't work

How is it GET|HEAD complaint/delete/{id} if you change the route to Route::delete described in the answer?

Either you use Route::delete or the Route::resource (if you created the controller using the artisan command)
